# not able to output stdout for each loop item in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Team,

I want to output the value of each stdout of item that I looped on. My case is to find directory size of list of dir passed in loop. so am not able to print out the directory name and size that am getting from the output of my command `du -sk /core` for example one case

task

```
- name: Calculate directories size
  command: "du -sk /{{ item }}"
  register: folder_size_raw
  with_items: "{{ directories }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
  tags: tag_directories_size

- set_fact:
    stdout_lines: []

- set_fact:
    stdout_lines: "{{ stdout_lines + item.stdout_lines }}"
  with_items: "{{ folder_size_raw.results }}"

- debug:
    msg: "This is a stdout line: {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ stdout_lines }}"
```

vars/main.yaml

```
#variables
directories: ["core", "home", "lib", "mnt", "root", "raid", "usr", "var/lib", "var"]
```

output

```
16:07:51  PLAY [Node_Operations] *********************************************************
16:07:51  TASK [node_operations : Calculate directories size] ****************************
16:07:51  Saturday 06 March 2021  00:07:51 +0000 (0:00:00.153)       0:00:00.153 ******** 
16:07:54  changed: [node1] => (item=core)
16:07:57  changed: [node1] => (item=home)
16:07:57  changed: [node1] => (item=lib)
16:07:57  changed: [node1] => (item=mnt)
16:07:58  changed: [node1] => (item=root)
16:07:59  changed: [node1] => (item=raid)
16:07:59  changed: [node1] => (item=usr)
16:10:28  changed: [node1] => (item=var/lib)
16:13:31  changed: [node1] => (item=var)
16:13:31
```

expected

```
16:07:51  PLAY [Node_Operations] *********************************************************
16:07:51  
16:07:51  TASK [node_operations : Calculate directories size] ****************************
16:07:51  Saturday 06 March 2021  00:07:51 +0000 (0:00:00.153)       0:00:00.153 ******** 
16:07:54  changed: [node1] => (item=core)
16:07:57  changed: [node1] => (item=home)
16:07:57  changed: [node1] => (item=lib)
16:07:57  changed: [node1] => (item=mnt)
16:07:58  changed: [node1] => (item=root)
16:07:59  changed: [node1] => (item=raid)
16:07:59  changed: [node1] => (item=usr)
16:10:28  changed: [node1] => (item=var/lib)
16:13:31  changed: [node1] => (item=var)
16:13:31 

This is a stdout line: 1GB /core 
This is a stdout line: 3GB /home
......
....
...
```

Comment: What about directly looping over `folder_size_raw.results` and debugging `item.stdout_lines`? Or you need an accumulator of the `item.stdout_lines` for other use? You can directly get the list of each attribute of a list with the `map` filter: `stdout_lines: "{{ folder_size_raw.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') }}"` without looping and accumulating.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible has built-in accounting of the results from loop iterations.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop

```yaml
---

- name: localhost
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    directories: ["home", "usr/share/doc", "usr/local"]
  tasks:

    - name: Calculate directories size
      command: "du -sk /{{ item }}"
      register: folder_size_raw
      with_items: "{{ directories }}"
      ignore_errors: yes
      register: dir_size_loop
      tags: tag_directories_size

    - debug:
        var: dir_size_loop['results']
```